# Existence of a given Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to \Bbb R $  be a continuous function with $\alpha(a)=a_0,\alpha(b)=b_0$. Let $c\in (a,b)$.
>
> Let 
>   \begin{align}
> f&:[a,b]\to \Bbb R\\ f&(x)= \begin{cases}
> 5, &\text{$x \in [a,c)$}\\
> 3, &x= c\\
> -1, & x\in (c,b]
> \end{cases}
> \end{align}
>
> Does $\int_a^b f d\alpha$ exist?

I tried considering a sequence of partitions $P_N=\{a=x_0,\dots, x_k=c,\dots x_N=b\}$ and computing $$\sum_{i=1}^N f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))$$

But, of course, I got no information from this (I just get that the first part equals $5(\alpha(x_{k-1})-\alpha(a))$ and similarly for the last part), but it seems that the sums differ if the choice of the $t_k\in[x_{k-1},c]$ are different. So my guess would be that this integral does not exist.

For reference, my definition is that $\int fd\alpha=L$ iff for any given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that for every refinement $P^*$
 of $P$ and every choice of $t_i$ we have that $$|\big (\sum_{P^*}f(t_i)(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})\big )- L| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the integral exists.

Hint: It's true that the value of one or two terms in the sum depends on the choice of $t_k$. But if $c-x_{k-1}$ is small enough then changing $t_k$ changes that term by less than $\epsilon$, because $\alpha$ is *continuous*. Similarly for the interval $[c,x_k]$, and similarly for the fact that what you call the first part, $5(\alpha(x_{k-1})-\alpha(a))$, depends on $x_{k-1}$.

Comment: Hmm I intuitively understand what you mean (refining a lot this partition I started with, I should be able to get  the difference in the definition I gave to be less than $\epsilon$), but I'm really having trouble writing this in more formal manner. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also, your answer makes me think that continuity  is needed only near $c$. Is this correct?

Comment: It's not quite that simple in general, but yes if you're integrating this function then continuity of $\alpha$ near $c$ is what's crucial. Regarding elaborating, I don't want to do your homework. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\alpha(t)-\alpha(c)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|t-c|<\delta$, and the existence of the integral follows from that.